# Permissions for Azure OMS Agent files

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, azure

I have two files that the Azure OMS agent reads/writes from that are world writable files.  Our vulnerability scanner (rapid 7) is picking these up as vulnerabilities. It's also poor practice in general.

```
/var/opt/microsoft/omsagent/{subscriptionid}/state/contentlocationcache.cache
/var/opt/microsoft/omsagent/{subscriptionid}/log/ODSIngestion.status
```

File permissions are respectively set to:

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 omsagent omiusers 
-rw-rw-rw- 1 omsagent omiusers
```

If I change the permissions to

```
-rw-rw---
```

I am unable to get scan data back from the device.  Does anyone know the permissions these files should be set to?  Microsoft doesn't seem to have documentation on these permissions in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `-rw-rw-r--`. The vulnerability scan is warning you that every other shouldn't write (w) on this file.

Comment: Ah, good call.  I'll try that out and hopefully the OMS agent doesn't freak out again.  Thanks